# Have someone + ing or Normal verb?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs, vocabulary, causatives

Would mind saying whether one of these sentences are incorrect?

> It's nice we *have someone* **taking** care of him.
>
> It's nice we *have someone* **take** care of him.

If both are correct, what are their differences?

Comment: Look at the second answer (using "clean" as the example verb) on this post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208233/have-somebody-do-something-vs-have-somebody-doing-something